# Pointwise Convergence but not Uniform Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

[image]

I couldn't see why it does not converge uniformly.

Is it because $\lim \limits_{j \to \infty}|\frac1j -1|$ does not converge to $0$?

(This is a problem from Steven Krantz's Real Analysis and Foundations.)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Take the sequence $x_j=j$, then $f_j(x_j)=1/j\to 0$.